# PySpark - Getting the latest date less than another given date

Tags: pyspark

I need some help. I have two dataframes, one has a few dates and the other has my significant data, catalogued by date.

It goes something like this:

First df, with the relevant data

```
+------+----------+---------------+
|    id| test_date|          score|
+------+----------+---------------+
|     1|2021-03-31|             94|
|     1|2021-01-31|             93|
|     1|2020-12-31|            100|
|     1|2020-06-30|             95|
|     1|2019-10-31|             58|
|     1|2017-10-31|             78|
|     2|2020-01-31|             79|
|     2|2018-03-31|             66|
|     2|2016-05-31|             77|
|     3|2021-05-31|             97|
|     3|2020-07-31|            100|
|     3|2019-07-31|             99|
|     3|2019-06-30|             98|
|     3|2018-07-31|             91|
|     3|2018-02-28|             86|
|     3|2017-11-30|             82|
+------+----------+---------------+
```

Second df, with the dates

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|   eval_date_1|   eval_date_2|   eval_date_3|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    2021-01-31|    2020-10-31|    2019-06-30|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Needed DF

```
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+
|    id|   eval_date_1| score_1 |   eval_date_2| score_2 |   eval_date_3| score_3 |
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+
|     1|    2021-01-31|       93|    2020-10-31|       95|    2019-06-30|       78|
|     2|    2021-01-31|       79|    2020-10-31|       79|    2019-06-30|       66|
|     3|    2021-01-31|      100|    2020-10-31|      100|    2019-06-30|       98|
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+---------+
```

So, for instance, for the first id, the needed df takes the scores from the second, fourth and sixth rows from the first df. Those are the most updated dates that stay equal to or below the eval_date on the second df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your main dataframe and `df_date` is the one which contains only dates.

```
from functools import reduce

from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W


df_final = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.join(b, on="id"),
    (
        df.join(
            F.broadcast(df_date.select(f"eval_date_{i}")),
            on=F.col(f"eval_date_{i}") >= F.col("test_date"),
        )
        .withColumn(
            "rnk",
            F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("test_date").desc())),
        )
        .where("rnk=1")
        .select("id", f"eval_date_{i}", "score")
        for i in range(1, 4)
    ),
)

df_final.show()
+---+-----------+-----+-----------+-----+-----------+-----+                     
| id|eval_date_1|score|eval_date_2|score|eval_date_3|score|
+---+-----------+-----+-----------+-----+-----------+-----+
|  1| 2021-01-31|   93| 2020-10-31|   95| 2019-06-30|   78|
|  3| 2021-01-31|  100| 2020-10-31|  100| 2019-06-30|   98|
|  2| 2021-01-31|   79| 2020-10-31|   79| 2019-06-30|   66|
+---+-----------+-----+-----------+-----+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Just to make it clear, in case anyone else has a similar problem, your solution said called the secondary df `df_date`, but in the coding you called it `df_score`.